# How to import javascript in rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api

I'm using the google visualization javascript api in my rails app and have included it like this in application.html.erb file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

For the script and following code to work, I need to be connected to the internet.  I instead took the contents of the above url and placed it in the assets>javascripts folder in my rails app and named it jsapi.js.  I then included the below in application.html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jsapi" %>
```

When I run my app when disconnected to the internet, I'm able to see the contents of the above file because this gets generated:

```
<script src="/assets/jsapi.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, the actual chart I'm trying to make doesn't work.  Any advice on why this is?  My full code for the javascript in my index.html.erb (actually using the library) is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var options = {
          title: 'Most common phrases in pro-Microsoft Reviews (<%= @reviews.count %> reviews analyzed)',
          vAxis: {title: 'Phrases',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
          animation:{
            duration: 2000,
            easing: 'out',}
        };

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Phrase', 'Frequency'],
            <% @frequency.each do |key,value| %>
                ['<%= key %>', <%= value %>],
            <% end %>
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      }
    </script>
```

I have a feeling that it's something to do with the code immediately above.  When I remove the first javascript snippet I included and am connected to the web, it works.

Comment: any exceptions when stuff is not working?

Comment: @ted  no, not getting any exceptions that i know of.  it's just the area where the chart should display doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the top of the jsapi.js from Google it would appear to be referencing other external JS files.   These are variables are used throughout the JS file.

```
google.loader.ServiceBase = 'https://www.google.com/uds';
google.loader.GoogleApisBase = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax';
```